# Read Rewritten URL - javascript

Tags: javascript, url-rewriting

I need to read the original URL from the rewritten path.

this is how i do url rewrite in my webapplication. I don't have codebehind in my application. So i read everything through javascript and call a webservice. While calling the webservice, i need to read query parameter ID and pass it.

Is my url rewrite method is right? if so, how can i read the original URL i.e. pages/products.aspx?ID=123. Because in my browser address bar it shows only product.aspx, i get the same through javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know whether right or wrong way, anyhow I managed to get the query string using JavaScript.

The query string was not visible in the browser window, but in the form tag it is available. So I get that using `document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].action`, and completed my task.

Comment: That's because you rewrote it into your form